# Inserting data into OpenERP through Object Object On Rails(OOOR)

Tags: odoo

I want to insert data into the postgresql database of OpenERP, I am able to fetch data from it using **ProductProduct.find(1)** method, but I've no idea how do I use OOOR insert data to the database through it.

Please help.

Comment: Please select the answer from the given response to close the workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert data just like in ActiveRecord in Rails. For a product for example:

`product = ProductProduct.find(1)

product.name = "New Name for product"

product.save`

Answer (score 0):

Openerp is providing `XMLRPC` webservice. You can call that web service and call the `create` method to insert your data.

You will get the help for webservice for openerp from http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a new record using Ooor

```
pc = ProductCategory.new(:name => 'Categ From Rails!')
#<ProductCategory:0xb702c42c @prefix_options={}, @attributes={"name"=>"Categ From Rails!"}>
pc.create
pc.id
```

For more info https://github.com/akretion/ooor